# Shell script, directory is writable strange behavior

Tags: shell, ubuntu, scripting, dash-shell

Here is `-w` option description from `test`'s man page :

```
   -w FILE
          FILE exists and write permission is granted
```

And as an example is better than a thousand words :

```
$ ls -ld /home/maxime/.gvfs
dr-x------ 2 maxime maxime 0 Aug  5 22:53 /home/maxime/.gvfs
$ [ -w /home/maxime/.gvfs ] && echo "is writable" 
is writable
$ touch /home/maxime/.gvfs/file
touch: cannot touch `/home/maxime/.gvfs/file': No such file or directory
```

As you can see, the directory shouldn't be writable : only `r` and `x` flags are set.
But, `test` says that I can write in it... First strange thing. Other one is what happens when I try to create a file in it : `No such file or directory`.

By the way, I'm running the above commands as user "maxime", and I'm using dash from Ubuntu 12.04.

Well, I'm a bit lost here, anyone got an explanation ?

Comment: Apart from ``test`` resolving to another binary rather than ``/usr/bin/test``, no idea. Could you try ``test -w /home/maxime/.gvfs; echo $?`` and see whether it's 1 or 0 ?

Comment: Here it is : `/usr/bin/test -w /home/maxime/.gvfs ; echo $?`. Output : `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.gvfs` is a special file, in fact a virtual file system created by `gvfs-fuse-daemon`. You should not use it directly.

Comment: Alright. In fact, in my shell script, I want to find any writable directory in user's home. Should I make an "exception" for `.gvfs` ?